# What's the issue with icing for too long?

Tags: natural-remedy, tendinopathy, cryotherapy

What's the issue with icing for too long, when used to treat a tendinopathy?

The only issue I am aware of is the risk of frostbite.

E.g. http://www.active.com/running/articles/do-s-and-don-ts-for-icing-injuries:

> Don't ice for more than 20 minutes or you'll risk frostbite. If your
>   skin looks red, it's a warning sign you're pushing it. Remove the ice
>   once you feel numbness.

Is there any other issue?

I am asking for three reasons:

- curiosity
- some ice patches tend to get pretty warm after 20 minutes, and doesn't seem to pose a risk of frosbites.
- patients sometime exercise right before sleeping, and may fall asleep during icing. Empirically, it didn't create the frostbite, so I wonder if it's okay.

Comment: I haven't found any answer so far.

Comment: So I am still interested if someone has any idea.